# Get the name of db from sql express

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, database-backups

I have used this connection string to connect my sql database to sql express automatically:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDBFileName=|DataDirectory|\DB\MyDBName.mdf; User ID=sa;Password=MyPass;Persist Security Info=True
```

everything works fine, but the problem is when i want to get backup from my db.The sql express changes the name of db when attach it so in backup query i get this error:

> Database 'MyDBName' does not exist.Make sure that the name is entered
>   correctly. BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

My backup query is:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDBName] TO DISK=N'" + filePath + "' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10;
```

Is there any way to get the current name of my db from sql express **OR** set the name of my db when attached automatically to sql express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First execute the following query and get database name

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName
```

i.e

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DB_NAME() AS dbName",your_connection);
 string name = cmd.executeScalar().ToString();
 //now do what ever you want to with db name
```